# Unable to clear Rails cache and see an updated template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

The previous programmer suddenly quit. They left no documentation about a Rails app they spent a year developing. I have now been given the task of making some changes. But I can not make changes to a template appear in the production site, if I ssh to the server and edit the templates in production.

The system:

```
  rake about

  Rails version             4.2.0
  Ruby version              2.2.3-p173 (x86_64-darwin15)
  RubyGems version          2.4.5.1
  Rack version              1.5
  JavaScript Runtime        Node.js (V8)
  Environment               development
  Database adapter          mysql2
```

I think the problem is the cache, but I tried:

```
  rake tmp:cache:clear
```

and:

```
  Rails.cache.clear
```

with no visible effect.

I am nervous about restarting the app since I have no instructions about how to start it. I am unsure of whether there are Cap scripts that are up to date.

On my machine, if I edit:

```
 apps/views/layouts/application.html.erb
```

then I see the change instantly, but if I ssh to production and make the same change, I don't see the change. There are some pages where I can edit their HTML template, and I see the changes right away, but not application.html.erb.

Assuming this problem is the cache, how should I clear the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it's most likely not a caching problem.

In production mode, all classes etc. are preloaded during the startup of the app. Ergo you must restart the server when making changes to anything in your Rails app.

When you SSH to your server and type

```
$ ps auxf
```

You should be able to see the flags used when starting the app previously.

Comment: The odd thing is that there are a few minor templates where (if I edit a file in production) I can make a change and see the change instantly. But on most templates, and certainly application.html.erb, I don't see my changes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I restarted the app. Still no changes, which makes me think that we are simply not using application.html.erb.

Comment: You can check in the controller if the action have something like
`layout false`, then it's not using the standard layout file

Comment: If you add your controller code it will be easier to check ;)

Comment: No, my theory was dumb. If I change the template locally, and run "rails -s" and check in my browser, I see the change, just like I expect. But when I push it to the server and restart the app, I still don't see the change. This is maddening.

Comment: Okay, turns out the problem was actually several problems together: misconfigured Capistrano scripts, out of date ssh deploy keys, non-existent documentation, non-existent error messages. But your suggestion of restarting the app was a good one.

Comment: Nice that you figured it out :)